# Breakline after a item of an array reactnative

Tags: react-native

I have item that are in array. I want to change the line after setting the first item and so on. I am getting the values in a row. But I want it in column. I am getting value as:

```
015245088    9823178404  9851108404
```

But I want value as:

```
015245088    
9823178404  
9823178404
```

I have implemented as follows:

```
 this.state = {
        contact: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: '015245088'
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: '9823178404'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: '9851108404'
            }
        ]
      }

<CardSection>
   <FontAwesomeIcon style={styles.contentStyle} icon={faPhone} />
      {
         this.state.contact.map((item, index) => (
           <TouchableOpacity
              key={item.id}
              style={styles.opacityStyle}
              onPress={()=>Linking.openURL(`tel:${item.name}`)}>                               

              <Text style={styles.contactStyle}>{item.name} </Text>

          </TouchableOpacity>
         ))
        }
     </CardSection>
```

Comment: Are you using Faltlist  or any mapping function? And can you share much more code?

Comment: Are you applying `flexDirection: 'row'` styles somewhere? Default display should be column and not row. You can just set your `flexDirection: 'column'` style somewhere in your container component and it should work Here are the docs - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox. Check this snack for an example - https://snack.expo.io/@jonoh/authentic-orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.state = {
        contact: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: '015245088'
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: '9823178404'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: '9851108404'
            }
        ]
      }

<CardSection>
   <FontAwesomeIcon style={styles.contentStyle} icon={faPhone} />
   <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
   {

      this.state.contact.map((item, index) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
           key={item.id}
           style={styles.opacityStyle}
           onPress={()=>Linking.openURL(`tel:${item.name}`)}>                               
           <Text style={styles.contactStyle}>{item.name} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
   }
   </View>
</CardSection>
```

Comment: it is incorrect to use `flex-direction`. style values need to be written using camel casing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `flexDirection` to `column`.
So, Just add the following styles to `styles.contentStyle`. Or wrap your `map` function with a `View` and add the following styles to it.

```
flexDirection: 'column'
flex: 1
```